# How to check the working time of application?

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, time

How can I check the evaluation processing time of my application.
For example how many time it needs to do A, B, C, A+C, B+C, ...

Comment: Keep a set of counter variables and increment them whenever you do an operation you want to track?

Comment: Are you actually looking to measure the time of the whole application, a part of the application, or do you want to measure how many times it does a certain thing (function or instruction)?

Comment: @Mats Petersson as you can see from my question I want to measure time for every combination of operations I am interested in. The whole working time is just combination off everything.

Comment: And what is A, B and C? Instructions or functions?

Comment: Parts of program - for example let A be the time that program spends to load a file, B - the time that program spends to apply some algorithm on the loaded file, C - the time to execute

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use `gettimeofday()` and use the `timersub()` function to get the difference.
2. You could use `clock()` and subtract the two times.  Remember to #include .

-Referenced from:

[How to subtract two gettimeofday instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668695/how-to-subtract-two-gettimeofday-instances)

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/50561/

[What is the best, most accurate timer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521146/what-is-the-best-most-accurate-timer-in-c)

EDIT:  Another option is chrono i/o.  Gives very high precision.
http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_io.html

Comment: What if I need accuracy with milliseconds?

Comment: another option for more resolution is chrono i/o.  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/duration_io/chrono_io.html

Comment: @philhan just updated that link to its new home

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux. Command 'time' can help you:

```
$time ./a.out 

real    0m0.137s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Then you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Use QueryPerformanceCounter().

```
LARGE_INTEGER s, e, f;

QueryPerformanceFrequency( &f );
QueryPerformanceCounter( &s );

// TO DO: add your code here

QueryPerformanceCounter( &e );


const __int64 durationMilliseconds = ( e.QuadPart - s.QuadPart ) * 1000 / f.QuadPart;
```